# How to perform Viewpager transition with Swipe Gestures

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-transitions, swipe-gesture, android-gesture

I got two activity which i intend to launch with swipe gestures. But the transition between activities were of a normal activity launch but i want something that would happen with viewpager, as you swipe horizontally.How do it do it? Here is my SwipeGestures Code..

public class SwipeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private GestureDetectorCompat gestureDetectorCompat;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe);


    gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, new GestureDetector.OnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {


            if(e2.getX()<e1.getX()){

                Intent intent = new Intent(SwipeActivity.this,BottomSheetActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();

            }


            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Now when i launch intent through swipe, i wanted something that would happen with ViewPager (which mean should be able to display next screen while swiping).

Thankyou,
Jay

Comment: "...wanted something would happen..."  ??? You mean like this? https://medium.com/@BashaChris/the-android-viewpager-has-become-a-fairly-popular-component-among-android-apps-its-simple-6bca403b16d4 Look into `PageTransformer`

Comment: I have already read that blog, but that specifies the delay of transition. Similar to page transition without having a viewpager.